# How to plot multiple functions on the same figure

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, graph

How can I plot the following 3 functions (i.e. `sin`, `cos` and the addition), on the domain `t`, in the same figure?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)

a = np.sin(t)
b = np.cos(t)
c = a + b
```

Answer (score 255, accepted):

To plot multiple graphs on the same figure you will have to do:

```
from numpy import *
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 400)
a = sin(t)
b = cos(t)
c = a + b

plt.plot(t, a, 'r') # plotting t, a separately 
plt.plot(t, b, 'b') # plotting t, b separately 
plt.plot(t, c, 'g') # plotting t, c separately 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 72):

Perhaps a more pythonic way of doing so.

```
from numpy import *
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = linspace(0,2*math.pi,400)
a = sin(t)
b = cos(t)
c = a + b

plt.plot(t, a, t, b, t, c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just use the function `plot` as follows

```
figure()
...
plot(t, a)
plot(t, b)
plot(t, c)
```

Comment: just a little change : plt.figure()

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work with figure, I give an example where you want to plot multiple ROC curves in the same figure:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
for item in range(0, 10, 1): 
    plt.plot(fpr[item], tpr[item])
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is an ROC curve?

Comment: Receiver operating characteristic. It's used in the context of stats to show how a hypothesis test behaves for a given threshold. For instance you may have a binary classifier that takes some input x, applies some function f(x) to it and predicts H1 if f(x) > t. t is your threshold that you use to decide whether to predict H0 or H1. Varying that threshold will yield different true positive rate-false positive rate pairs. The ROC curve captures that. The name comes from early applications of hypothesis testing in the military to decide whether a radar was raising a false alarm @Cheng

Answer (score 2):

A pretty concise method is to concatenate the function values horizontally to make an array of shape `(len(t), 3)` and call `plot()`.

```py
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)

a = np.sin(t)
b = np.cos(t)
c = a + b

plt.plot(t, np.c_[a, b, c]);
```

If the data doesn't come from a numpy array and you don't want the numpy dependency, `zip()` is your friend.

```py
plt.plot(t, list(zip(a, b, c)));
```

Since there are 3 different graphs on a single plot, perhaps it makes sense to insert a legend in to distinguish which is which. That can be done easily by passing the label.

```py
plt.plot(t, np.c_[a, b, c], label=['sin', 'cos', 'sin+cos']);
plt.legend();
```

[image: img1]