# subplotting missingno library plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, missingno

What is the easiest way to get subplots of [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno/) via `msno.matrix()` for df1 , df2, df3 . I already checked [this issue](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno/issues/26)  and below solution didn't work due to `TypeError
'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing` and updated pandas and missingno based on [that issue](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno/issues/35).

```
fig = msno.matrix(df)
grid_ax = fig.axes[0]
my_subplots = plt.subplots(2, 2)
my_subplots[0][0] = grid_ax
```

I used below snippet but was unsuccessful. I don't know how shuold I returen the `ax`:

```
#Set up the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2 , figsize=(8,8) , squeeze=False)

plt.subplot(131) 
msno.matrix(df1)

plt.subplot(132) 
msno.matrix(df2)

plt.subplot(133) 
msno.matrix(df3)

plt.savefig('comparison.png') 
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Please leave a general solution we can just by replacing different df we can use it.
Have a nice evening

Comment: It's not possible due to [this line](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno/blob/1d67f91fbab0695a919c6bb72c796db57024e0ca/missingno/missingno.py#L51) creating the figure internally. There are workarounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/4124317)    or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45812071/4124317) but they have unwanted side effects. The solution here would be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600211/figure-into-a-subplot-matplotlib/53600501#53600501), recreating the `matrix` function with the option to pass in an axes.

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
```

I would try to take out the index after the .axes, like this:

```
fig = msno.matrix(df)
grid_ax = fig.axes
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It didn't work for `msno.matrix` and throw out `TypeError: 'Figure' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to Iannes' answer: missingno docs stipulate to specify `inline=False`, which will cause missingno to return the underlying `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object.

So the provided code should be:

```
fig = msno.matrix(df, inline=False)
grid_ax = fig.axes
```