# pandas multiple dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. They have the same structure but they come from two different model. Basically, I would like to compare them in order to find the differences. The first thing that I would like to do is to plot two rows, the first from the first data frames and the second from the other.

This is what I do:
I read the two csv file,

```
PRICES   = pd.read_csv('test_model_1.csv',sep=';',index_col=0, header = 0)
PRICES_B = pd.read_csv('bench_mark.csv',sep=';',index_col=0, header = 0)
```

then I plot the 8th column of both, as:

```
rowM  = PRICES.iloc[8]
rowB  = PRICES_B.iloc[8]
rowM.plot()
rowB.plot()
```

It does not seem the correct way. Indeed, I am not able to choose the labels or the legends.

This the results:
[comparison between the 8th row of the first dataframe and the 8th row of the second dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTksc.png)

Someone could suggest me the correct way to compare the two data frames and plot some of the selected columns?

Comment: you'll need `matplotlib.pyplot` in order to plot multiple data on the same graph

Comment: Dear  Mayeul sgc,
you are suggesting to pass the rows selected to a matrix and to use the standatd matplotlib to plot them?
thanks again

Comment: You don't need to do that, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22276109/4350650) answer

Comment: Dear all, Dear Mayeul sgc,
thanks, it seems to work. However, I have a strange behavior with x labels. In my opinion is due to data-frame data.  Can I ask here?
thanks

Comment: use `plt.xlabel()` or `plt.ylabel()` to adjust label to your needs

Comment: Dear all, Dear @Mayeul sgc,
the problem is that the xticx name become like the id name of the dataframe columns. My feeling is that "rowM  = PRICES.iloc[8]" has two informations: value and column id. When I plot "rowM" with plt.plot(rowM), matplolib is not able to handle it and gives me strange results. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

lets prepare some test data:

```
mtx1 = np.random.rand(10,8)*1.1+2
mtx2 = np.random.rand(10,8)+2

df1 = pd.DataFrame(mtx1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(mtx2)
```

example output for df1:

```
Out[60]: 
              0         1         2         3
    0  2.604748  2.233979  2.575730  2.491230
    1  3.005079  2.984622  2.745642  2.082218
    2  2.577554  3.001736  2.560687  2.838092
    3  2.342114  2.435438  2.449978  2.984128
    4  2.416953  2.124780  2.476963  2.766410
    5  2.468492  2.662972  2.975939  3.026482
    6  2.738153  3.024694  2.916784  2.988288
    7  2.082538  3.030582  2.959201  2.438686
    8  2.917811  2.798586  2.648060  2.991314
    9  2.133571  2.162194  2.085843  2.927913
```

now let's plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

i = range(0,len(df1.loc[6,:]))   # from 0 to 3
plt.plot(i,df1.loc[6,:]) # take whole row 6
plt.plot(i,df2.loc[6,:]) # take whole row 6
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Daer all, Dear @Alexey,
It works. It is a good procedure.
Thanks to everyone