# How can i plot multiple linear graphics of a loop array?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
          CODE      DATE    MONTH_DAY  PP       PP_INTERPOL
0       472606FA 2001-01-01   01-01    0.0         0.0
1       472606FA 2001-01-02   01-02    0.0         0.1
2       472606FA 2001-01-03   01-03    0.7         0.5
3       472606FA 2001-01-04   01-04    NaN         NaN
4       472606FA 2001-01-05   01-05    NaN         NaN
         ...        ...     ...    ...        ...
248220  47E2A75C 2021-04-26   04-26    0.3         0.3
248221  47E2A75C 2021-04-27   04-27    0.5         0.4
248222  47E2A75C 2021-04-28   04-28    0.5         0.5
248223  47E2A75C 2021-04-29   04-29    0.8         0.8
248224  47E2A75C 2021-04-30   04-30    NaN         NaN
```

I'm calculating some formulas for every code. So i did this code:

```
for code, data in df.groupby('CODE'):

  rmsef1=np.sqrt(np.nanmean((data['PP']-interpolated_array1)**2))
  rmsef2=np.sqrt(np.nanmean((data['PP']-interpolated_array2)**2))
  rmsef3=np.sqrt(np.nanmean((data['PP']-interpolated_array3)**2))
  rmsef4=np.sqrt(np.nanmean((data['PP']-interpolated_array4)**2))
  rmsef5=np.sqrt(np.nanmean((data['PP']-interpolated_array5)**2))
  .
  .
  .
  .
  rmsef20=np.sqrt(np.nanmean((data['PP']-interpolated_array20)**2)) 

  rmses=np.array([rmsef1,rmsef2,rmsef3,rmsef4,
       rmsef5,rmsef6,rmsef7,rmsef8,
       rmsef9,rmsef10,rmsef11,rmsef12,
       rmsef13,rmsef14,rmsef15,rmsef16,
       rmsef17,rmsef18,rmsef19,rmsef20])
```

So i'll get as many rmses variables as the number of codes (rmses is a array of 20 float values). I want to plot all of this rmses in a
same graphic (linear plot), something similar to this image:

[image]

So i'm not sure how or where i should use the `plt.plot`. Or maybe i need to create another loop.

Would you mind to help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot multiple functions on the same figure, in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276066/how-to-plot-multiple-functions-on-the-same-figure-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @woblob srry no. Cause i have more than rmses to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add an additional loop. Inside your already existing for loop, add `plt.plot` immediately after computing the `rmses` values. Depending on how many `codes` you have in your dataframe you may want to add a `legend` to make your chart easier to read. You can do that by adding `label=code` as argument of `plt.plot`, and add `plt.legend` outside the loop.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

for code, data in df.groupby('CODE'):

    rms_1_20 = [data.iloc[i]['PP'] for i in range(20)]
    rmses = rms_1_20  # just to explicitate the aquisition of 20 RMS values.

    plt.plot(range(len(rmses)), rmses, label=code)

plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image: plt_rmses]